# How to shut down my computer?

Tags: shutdown

I can't find a dialogue anywhere on the desktop (like on Windows Start/shutdown) to shut down Ubuntu. I downloaded and ran the Ubuntu live CD and after I ran it, I couldn't shut it down. I had to hold the on/off key on my computer for 4 seconds to shut down my computer to get back into Windows. If there is a button somewhere, why is it not obvious?

Comment: And you are using Ubuntu (Unity) or another flavour (as it varies between flavours)?

Answer (score 9):

Go to the upper right corner and use the gear menu to select Shut Down.

[image]

Comment: depending on the theme you are using the icon can change (a small computer for example) but it's located on the same position (upper right)

Answer (score 3):

You can also momentarily press the power button, and a pop up dialog will appear with buttons for suspend, hibernate, restart and shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a terminal and have root access how about the shutdown command:

```
shutdown -h now
man shutdown for more detail
```

Answer (score 1):

## Here are 3 ways:

1. You can type `Ctl+Alt+T` to bring up the Terminal. Then you can type
   either halt, or shutdown. With the shutdown command you need to
   specify a time. If you type shutdown 1, it will shutdown in one
   minute, if you type shutdown 5 it will wait 5 minutes and so on.
2. The final option I know of is to add a keyboard shortcut by going to
   the top right corner and entering the System
   Settings>Keyboard>Shortcuts, then you'll click on the Custom
   Shortcuts text and click the + icon to add a custom shortcut. Just
   type in Shutdown or whatever you wish for the name. In the command
   dialog box type: `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper -s`
   and click save. Now you'll need to click where it says disabled, and
   you'll see the text change from disabled to New Shortcut. Now type a
   key command like Ctrl+Alt+End and save it.
3. Or as the others have pointed out, you can use the power button.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T brings up a new terminal tab only if you already are in gnome-terminal.

Comment: The correct shortcut for terminal from anywhere is ctrl-alt-t

Comment: Yep, I don't know why I typed Shift. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: What's wrong with `[sudo] shutdown -h now` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to log in first.
Press Esc, then log in, following that shut down via the top right corner.

I believe it's intended to keep unauthorized users from getting into the bios settings easily.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and running

```
shutdown 0
```

worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04