# How to Shut down Ubuntu by using keyboard?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shutdown

How to shut Down Ubuntu by using Keyboard only. [Like Windows style]
In windows XP if we press <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> this keys for shutdown.
and <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> for restart computer.
<kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for Hibernet 
etc.
How can I do it in Ubuntu.
Any keyboard shortcut for it? and without terminal also.
I read:-
[How to shut down the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424520/how-to-shut-down-the-system)
[How to shut down my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95728/how-to-shut-down-my-computer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shut down computer from keyboard](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53263/shut-down-computer-from-keyboard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could open terminal by pressing `CTRL+ALT+T`

then simply type :

-for shutdown:

```
sudo shutdown
```

or

```
sudo poweroff
```

-for restart:

```
sudo reboot
```

As far as  I am aware, there isn't a system shortcut for shutdown, but you could create one. Read [Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts to Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91501/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-to-shutdown)

Comment: I want keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a nice one for you:

### Shutting down by using a hotkey

1. Install `consolekit`:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install consolekit
   ```

or use the Ubuntu Software Center: [consolekit [image: Install consolekit]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=consolekit)

2. Press <kbd>Super</kbd>, then type *Keyboard*, then click on the Keyboard icon
3. Click on *Hotkeys*
4. Click on *Custom hotkeys*
5. Add a new entry by clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign:

Name: `Shutdown`

Command:

```
    /usr/bin/dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

6. Now click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, then click in the second column to assign a hotkey.
7. Press any hotkey combination you desire. For instance: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
8. Enjoy!

---

### Reboot, hibernate, suspend

If you want to **restart** instead, replace said command by:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

If you need to **hibernate**, replace it by:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

Finally, if you're looking for a **suspend** shortcut, use this one:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

---

### References

- [Majal](https://askubuntu.com/users/101985/majal)'s solution at https://askubuntu.com/a/385316/18510
- RetroX' [post at the Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=127962)

Comment: nice one :) . But what about Restart and Hibernate?

Comment: @MadhavNikam: updated

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in to a graphical session

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
sudo poweroff
```

If you are logged in to a ssh or vty session

```
sudo poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo shutdown -P now

or

sudo telinit 0